# Getting string input in C unless empty string is found

Tags: c, string, loops, input

I am trying to get the user to enter string in a loop unless the string is found to be empty.

This is my attempt and I tried couple of different ways but I have the same problem. the loop keeps going even when I don't enter any thing.

***Code***

```
char string[100];

do{
    fgets(string,100,stdin);
} while (string[0] != '\0');
```

Unfortunately, when I run this the output is something like this:

***Output***

```
> hello
> world
> test
>
>
```

I also tried using `scanf()` instead of `fgets()` but the same issue is still there.

Comment: Oh that worked, Thanks! but what if I used scanf?

Comment: *but what if I used scanf?*  Don't use `scanf()` if you want to be able to handle bad input with any reliability.  If `scanf()` fails, you really don't know what state your input stream is in.  When you do something like `fgets()` and then maybe `sscanf()` to parse the string, at least then you know exactly where your input stream is even if the data is bad.  If you're reading from something like a pipe (because the user redirected input with something like `yourProgram < inputDataFile` you can't seek back to a previous location to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `fgets` is pretty simple. As a feature, you can test to see it the input contains a newline. If not, there are pending characters.
`scanf` is possible using a scanset. `%99[^\n]` will scan up to 99 characters that are not a newline. `%*c` will consume the newline. If the only character is a newline then the scanset will fail and scanf will return 0. If more than 99 characters are entered, `%*c` will consume a character that is not a newline. `fgets` does not have that problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void) {
    char string[100] = "";
    int result = 0;

    printf ( "using fgets\nenter a blank line to stop\n");
    do {
        fgets ( string, sizeof string, stdin);
    } while ( string[0] != '\n');

    printf ( "using scanf\nenter a blank line to stop\n");
    do {
        result = scanf ( "%99[^\n]%*c", string);
    } while ( result == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

With `ungetc`, if scanf reads too many characters, the last character can be put back in the stream if it is not a newline.

```
    char last = 0;

    do {
        result = scanf ( "%99[^\n]%c", string, &last);
        if ( EOF == result) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "scanf EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
        if ( '\n' != last) {
            ungetc ( last, stdin);
        }
    } while ( result == 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strcmp` function to check whether the input is empty or not:

```
char str[50];
while(strcmp(gets(str), "") != 0){
    printf("Output: %s\n", str);
}
```

`strcmp` function returns 0  when both strings are found to be identical.